# Convert Excel style date with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date, datetime

I have to parse an xml file which gives me datetimes in Excel style; for example: `42580.3333333333`.

Does Pandas provide a way to convert that number into a regular `datetime` object?

Comment: see also [How to convert a given ordinal number (from Excel) to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29387137/10197418)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

OK I think the easiest thing is to construct a `TimedeltaIndex` from the floats and add this to the scalar datetime for `1900,1,1`:

```
In [85]:
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[42580.3333333333, 10023]})
df

Out[85]:
           date
0  42580.333333
1  10023.000000

In [86]:
df['real_date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
df

Out[86]:
           date                  real_date
0  42580.333333 2016-07-31 07:59:59.971200
1  10023.000000 1927-06-12 00:00:00.000000
```

OK it seems that excel is a bit weird with it's dates thanks @ayhan:

```
In [89]:
df['real_date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
df

Out[89]:
           date                  real_date
0  42580.333333 2016-07-29 07:59:59.971200
1  10023.000000 1927-06-10 00:00:00.000000
```

See related: [How to convert a python datetime.datetime to excel serial date number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574793/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-datetime-to-excel-serial-date-number#comment49502311_9574948)

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Is there a way to change the date to format ddmmyyyy in the same command? Appreciate any help here.. Also, I tried on my dataset and noticed each date was incremented by 2 using the first code, second code gave correct dates though.

Answer (score 38):

you can directly parse with `pd.to_datetime`, with keywords `unit='D'` and `origin='1899-12-30'`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'xldate': [42580.3333333333]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['xldate'], unit='D', origin='1899-12-30')

df['date']
Out[2]: 
0   2016-07-29 07:59:59.999971200
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

*further reading:*

- [What is story behind December 30, 1899 as base date?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev)
- an [answer from Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387450/10197418) how to handle excel ordinal value < 60 correctly

Answer (score 16):

You can use the 3rd party [`xlrd`](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library before passing to [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import xlrd

def read_date(date):
    return xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[42580.3333333333, 10023]})

df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(read_date), errors='coerce')

print(df)

           date                 new
0  42580.333333 2016-07-29 08:00:00
1  10023.000000 1927-06-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to solve it with "apply lambda" for pd.Series:

```
xl_date = 42580

df['DATE SERIES'] = df['DATE SERIES'].apply(lambda x: datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + xldate - 2))
```