# Excel binary Date field converted to numpy int64

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have an binary excel file with DATE column with value '7/31/2020'.

Upon reading the file the DATE value is getting converted to numpy.int64 with value 44043.

Can you tell me how to stop this conversion or getting the date as is given in excel.

This is my code to read the excel file

```
>>df = pd.read_excel('hello.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')
>>df[DATE][0]
>>44043
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the integer value is the number of days since the 0th of January 1900. But the 0th of January doesn't exist: there seems to be a fudge factor of `2` involved here.

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=44043 - 2)
>>> d
datetime.date(2020, 7, 31)
>>> d.isoformat()
'2020-07-31'
>>> d.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
'07/31/2020'
```

See the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) docs for other formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the column as a date format when reading it in:

```
df = pd.read_excel('hello.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb', parse_dates=[DATE])
```

`DATE` is the variable with the column name expected to be in date format.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

By adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/14851404), you could use this snippet:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(filename_xlsb, engine="pyxlsb")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["xldate"], unit="D", origin="1899-12-30")
```

Note you must NOT pass `parse_date=` argument to [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), otherwise the related columns gets `object` dtype and [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) fails.