# Converting Julian to calendar date using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert Julian codes to calendar dates in pandas using :

```
pd.to_datetime(43390, unit = 'D', origin = 'Julian')
```

This is giving me ValueError: origin Julian cannot be converted to a Timestamp

Comment: Is the 'date' 43390 from Excel?  If so, these links might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487

Answer (score 0):

You need to set origin = '**j**ulian'

```
pd.to_datetime(43390, unit = 'D', origin = 'julian')
```

but this number (43390) throws

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: 43390 is Out of Bounds for origin='julian'
```

because the bounds are from 2333836 to 2547339
(Timestamp('1677-09-21 12:00:00') to Timestamp('2262-04-11 12:00:00'))

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - using Julian for origin didn't work

Method 2 - using excel start date to calculate other dates. All other date values will be referenced from excel default start date.

Finally this worked for me.

```
pd.to_datetime(43390, unit = 'D', origin=pd.Timestamp("30-12-1899"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works only for **6** digit julian value. It also handles the calendar date for leap and non-leap years.


A Julian date is considered as **"CYYDDD"**. Where **C** represents century, **YY** represents Year and **DDD** represents total days which are then further defined in Days and Months.

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    jul_date = '120075'
    add_days = int(jul_date[3:6])
    cal_date = pd.to_datetime(datetime.strptime(str(19+int(jul_date[0:1]))+jul_date[1:3]+'-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'))-timedelta(1)+pd.DateOffset(days= add_days)
    print(cal_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

**output:** 2020-03-15

**without timedelta(1):** 2020-03-16

Here datetime.strptime function is being used to cast date type from string to date.

%Y represents year in 4 digit (1980)

%m & %d represents month and day in digits.

strftime('%Y-%m-%d') is used to remove timestamp from the date.

timedelta(1) :- It's used to minus one day from the date because we've concatenated year with '01-01'. so when total no's of days being split to days and months, one day will not be extra.