# How can I convert Date column datatype from int64 to Date in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python. I have been trying to convert datatype of date column from int64 to date in jupyter notebook but whenever I try something I get the format correct but all the rows in the file shows same date. I don't understand what's wrong.

Date
43390
43599
43605
43329
43330
43604
43601

After I use any function- for example:
df["DATE2"] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df["DATE"]))
df[["DATE","DATE2"]].head()

I get this:

DATE                                    DATE2
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043390   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043390
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043599   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043599
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043605   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043605
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043329   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043329
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043330   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043330

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please put your code here and a sample of your dataframe? This will help the others find a solution for you.

Comment: Hi Eduardo and Chris,
I have attached the screenshot above. Please click on Screenshot you will find it. Also I am adding the code here again.
I have got date in this format:
DATE
43390
43599



Whenever I use any function 
for eg: 
df["DATE2"] = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df["DATE"]))
df[["DATE","DATE2"]].head()

I get this:
 DATE                                           DATE2
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043390 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043390
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043599 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043599
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043605 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043605

Comment: This looks like Excel styled dates, try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas). ie try `import datetime as dt` and `df['DATE2'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['DATE'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: I am getting this date in every column : 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000043390
The last 5 numbers are the ones which I have got in the original file which have int64 as the datatype. 
So, basically 1970-01-01 00:00:00.0000 is common in every row appended by the last 5 numbers of int64 file.