# TypeError on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have an error trying to convert integer numbers to DateTime format on a CSV file using Pandas.
The code I'm using is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

data=pd.read_csv("Dataset.csv",low_memory=False)
data.Date = data.Date.apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

The DataFrame is:
[image]

The error is:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thank you!!

Comment: maybe try data.Date = data.Date.astype(str) before you execute the lambda function?

Comment: Hi @ba123nas, not working. I have this error: ValueError: time data '42737' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: First of all, `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Date'` error should raise.

Comment: What is the int represent?  Is it days after some date? Is it microseconds after 1970?

Comment: that looks like Excel dates - which seems to be days from some epoch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas

Comment: @AsishM. Thank you!! That's the answer! It was an epoch, now it is converted! Thanks for you help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)