# How to transform a 5 digit format to %Y-%d-%m in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta

So i have a column "Date" that holds dates in a 5 digit format. i´m trying to create a new column with the format i want (%Y-%d-%m), but the loop show below just don´t stops.

`for u in df["Date"]: df["DateNew"] = datetime.date(1900,1,28) + datetime.timedelta(days=u)`

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How does this "5-digit format" look like? And by "column" you mean pandas DataFrame column?

Comment: The dates are written in numbers between 42371 and 43475. And, yes, i mean a pandas DF column. Thank you!

Comment: I understand that the 5 digits are certain number of days, so what i tried in the loop was to sum the number of days to the date where "the count started".

Comment: ok this looks like the format `Excel` uses. I've given an answer how to parse them with `pd.to_datetime` here: [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/10197418). In general, have another look at [ask] and try to come up with a [mre] - you'll get good answers to your problem much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In datetime you have access to all of the different pieces of date formats.  Here are a couple of examples of accessing and printing them out.

```
newDate = datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0, 0)
print(mewDate.strftime("%Y-%M-%d"))
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but this doesnt really answer my question. The problem is that neither pandas nor datetime recognize this 5-digit format, so i need to manually transform the dates.

Comment: from dateutil.parser import parse and then date = parse(date).  This works with almost any date format I've thrown at it and converts it to a datetime consumable format.