# How to convert Dataframe containing float and nan values to datetime python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe float column as:

```
data = {'mydate': [23131.0,23131.0,np.nan,22677.0,22554.0,np.nan,23131.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['mydate'])

         mydate 
0        23131.0              
1        23131.0              
2        NaN              
3        22677.0              
4        22554.0              
5        NaN              
6        23131.0
```

It contains null values. I am trying to convert it to datetime python using the following code

```
def dayym(unit):
    dates = {date:((epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=date))) for date in unit.unique()}
    return unit.map(dates)

df.loc[:,'mydate']= dayym(df['mydate'])
```

with the following error:

```
    dates = {date:((epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=date))) for date in unit.unique()}
  File "central_read.py", line 18, in <dictcomp>
    dates = {date:((epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=date))) for date in unit.unique()}
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Any ideas. I am out of them at this point.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
[Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: data = {'mydate': [23131.0,23131.0,np.nan,22677.0,22554.0,np.nan,23131.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['mydate'])

Comment: what does 23131 represent? Is it a relative number to another date?

Comment: see [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38454403/10197418) if it's excel time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is epoch, so used `1900-01-01` in parameter `origin`, also is necessary add `unit='d'` fo days and `errors='coerce'` for convert missing or wrong values to `NaT` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], errors='coerce', unit='d', origin='1900-01-01')
print (df)    
      mydate
0 1963-05-02
1 1963-05-02
2        NaT
3 1962-02-02
4 1961-10-02
5        NaT
6 1963-05-02
```

If need `epoch` is `1970-01-01` is possible use:

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], errors='coerce', unit='d', origin='unix')

#default value, so should be removed
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], errors='coerce', unit='d')
print (df)    
      mydate
0 2033-05-01
1 2033-05-01
2        NaT
3 2032-02-02
4 2031-10-02
5        NaT
6 2033-05-01
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert a float to datetime and ignore np.nan values, you can use [`pd.to_datetime with errors='coerce'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'mydate': [23131.0,23131.0,np.nan,22677.0,22554.0,np.nan,23131.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mydate'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
```

This will give you:

```
                         mydate
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000023131
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000023131
2                           NaT
3 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000022677
4 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000022554
5                           NaT
6 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000023131
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.dropna()` to drop them

```
df['mydate'] = df['mydate'].dropna().apply(daymm)
```

Comment: dates = {date:((epoch + datetime.timedelta(days=date))) for date in unit.unique()}
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'unique'