# Apply pandas to_datetime function to excel date format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i decided to practice with to_datetime function , for this purpose i have changed  source format of date  as an integers  , here is after  reading excel file, how each column looks like

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_excel("pivot.xlsx")
#data["Date"] =pd.to_datetime(data["Date"],format='%d%m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)
print(data.head())
```

result is  :

```
   Order ID   Product    Category  Amount   Date         Country
0         1   Carrots  Vegetables    4270  42375   United States
1         2  Broccoli  Vegetables    8239  42376  United Kingdom
2         3    Banana       Fruit     617  42377   United States
3         4    Banana       Fruit    8384  42379          Canada
4         5     Beans  Vegetables    2626  42379         Germany
```

in source, dateformat of date column is following 1/6/2016
so when i have apply to_datetime function, i  have got following result :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data =pd.read_excel("pivot.xlsx")
data["Date"] =pd.to_datetime(data["Date"],format='%d%m%y',infer_datetime_format=True)
print(data.head())

result :
   Order ID   Product  ...                          Date         Country
0         1   Carrots  ... 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042375   United States
1         2  Broccoli  ... 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042376  United Kingdom
2         3    Banana  ... 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042377   United States
3         4    Banana  ... 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042379          Canada
4         5     Beans  ... 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042379         Germany
```

how can i  fix it? in excel starting date is 1900 right? how can i apply it? is it possible to return real dates from those integers?

Comment: I believe you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/8998310)

Comment: thanks for  help, but it gives me   date with two days in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `openpyxl.utils.datetime.from_excel()` method.

```
from openpyxl.utils.datetime import from_excel


df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(from_excel)

print(df)


   Order ID   Product    Category  Amount       Date         Country
0         1   Carrots  Vegetables    4270 2016-01-06   United States
1         2  Broccoli  Vegetables    8239 2016-01-07  United Kingdom
2         3    Banana       Fruit     617 2016-01-08   United States
3         4    Banana       Fruit    8384 2016-01-10          Canada
4         5     Beans  Vegetables    2626 2016-01-10         Germany
```

Comment: inside  bracket, what does from excel   denotes?

Comment: @datodatuashvili it denotes the improted function from `openpyxl`  see [the source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/datetime.html#from_excel) here `.apply` is just applying the funcion on the entire row iteratively.