# How to read date from an excel file in python?

Tags: python, excel, datetime, time-series

I have an excel file that its first column is written as 31.12.2018 23.30 and it continues for a year. how can I convert this in python in order to change it in a way that I could get the year, month, day, and hour separately. I want to use it for a machine learning project to see whether my time series data is stationary or non_stationary.

Comment: are you already able to read it into python string?

Comment: and assuming you already read it, do you get the formatted date ("31.12.18 23:30") or the "serial" Excel date value, where the integer part is the number of days from 01.01.1900 and the decimal part is the time?

Comment: like [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38454403/10197418)?

Comment: You should take a look at `pandas` library. That would be the best way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for helping ... actually I want to have a separate array for the month and another array for the year and another for the day after importing the column from excel into python

Answer (score 1):

You can use [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You can [load an excel sheet](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file) using it and get data from it.

Example:

```py
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb2 = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
>>> print(wb2.sheetnames)
['Sheet2', 'New Title', 'Sheet1']
```