# Handling datetime column In pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, xlsb

I want to read xlsb file in pandas.
and I have 3 datetime column
1st column format is (2021-5-31 01:20:23 )
2nd column format (total time) is ( 01:20:23 )
3st column format is ( 01:20:23 am )

but when I am reading the file I am getting column 46090.0

Is there any method that can read the excel column as it is?

Comment: values like `46090.0` seem to be Excel serial dates that did not get converted correctly. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/10197418) on how to convert them in pure pandas.

Comment: @MrFuppes - Thanks, added to dupes.