# Python datetime to Excel serial date conversion

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

The following code converts a string into a timestamp. The timestamp comes out to: 1646810127.

However, if I use Excel to convert this date and time into a float I get: 44629,34.
I need the Excel's output from the Python script.

I have tried with a few different datetime strings to see if there is any pattern in between the two numbers, but cannot seem to find any.

Any thoughts on how I get the code to output 44629,34?

Much appreciated

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2022-03-09 08:15:27'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)

print(date_time_obj.timestamp())

>>output:
Date: 2022-03-09
Time: 08:15:27
Date-time: 2022-03-09 08:15:27
1646810127.0
```

Comment: btw. I'd suggest to change the title of the question to "Python datetime to Excel serial date conversion" (or similar) for findability of the question. It's not actually about *formatting* in the sense of producing a certain string representation.

Comment: I have edited the title according to your suggestion. Thank you once again for you assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate the timedelta of your datetime object versus Excel's "day zero", then divide the total_seconds of the timedelta by the seconds in a day to get Excel serial date:

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2022-03-09 08:15:27'
UTC = datetime.timezone.utc

dt_obj = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_time_str).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
day_zero = datetime.datetime(1899,12,30, tzinfo=UTC)

excel_serial_date = (dt_obj-day_zero).total_seconds()/86400

print(excel_serial_date)
# 44629.3440625
```

Note: I'm setting time zone to UTC here to avoid any ambiguities - adjust as needed.

Since the question is tagged `pandas`, you'd do the same thing here, only that you don't need to set UTC as pandas assumes UTC by default for naive datetime:

```
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Timestamp('2022-03-09 08:15:27')

excel_serial_date = (ts-pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30')).total_seconds()/86400

print(excel_serial_date)
# 44629.3440625
```

---

See also:

- background: [What is story behind December 30, 1899 as base date?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f1eef5fe-ef5e-4ab6-9d92-0998d3fa6e14/what-is-story-behind-december-30-1899-as-base-date?forum=accessdev)
- inverse operation: [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38454403/10197418)

Comment: Aha. Yes of course. Makes sense that they may not use the same day zero. Thank you!

Comment: @AlbaTroes what I named "day zero" is called "epoch" most of the time I think ;-) So the "Unix epoch" would be 1970-01-01 midnight UTC.