# ParserError: year 44091 is out of range: 44091.57292

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I am getting a parse error while trying to extract the year from the Registration date column where data is in format dd/mm/yy hh:mm: ss.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For a .csv file when I am performing pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Registration Date']).year I was getting the above mentioned error. However pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Registration Date']).year worked for xlsx file. But I want to understand why this didn't work for .csv file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)