# pandas : convert float64 to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have data from excel converted into pandas data frame:
The column with dates is formatted to float and looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [44793.170428, 44793.182118, 44793.192697]})
```

[image]

How can I convert it to date time so that the result looks like in excel:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`pandas.TimedeltaIndex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.html) with [**`datetime`**](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/datetime.html) then [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) :

```
import datetime

df['A'] = (pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['A'], unit='d') + datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)).date

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
            A
0  2022-08-20
1  2022-08-20
2  2022-08-20

print(df.dtypes)
A    datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use:

```
df['A'] = [pd.to_datetime(x, unit='d') - pd.DateOffset(years=70) for x in df['A']]
```

Output:

```
                              A
0 2022-08-21 04:05:24.979200000
1 2022-08-21 04:22:14.995199488
2 2022-08-21 04:37:29.020800000
```