# excel binary date file transformed into strange digit

Tags: pandas

I have an excel binary file that looks like this:

[image]

```
ird
1/1/2023
9/9/2023
-
```

When I read this data with pandas i get this:

```
from pathlib import WindowsPath
p = WindowsPath(r'C:\Users\data\book.xlsb')
df = pd.read_excel(p)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)


     ird
0  44927
1  45178
2      -
ird    object
dtype: object
```

Why does the dates get converted to these strange numbers ? I cannot find the reason for this.

Comment: Maybe because the read_excel and/or print call does not fully process the cell metadata?  I mean, it's all numbers anyway, at the end of the day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working converting to timedeltas and add `1899-12-30` for read native excel format with `-` values:

```
df = (pd.read_excel(p, 
                   parse_dates=['ird'],
                   date_parser = lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='D', errors='coerce') + 
                                           pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30')))


print (df)
         ird
0 2023-01-01
1 2023-09-09
2        NaT
```

Comment: i tried all 3, it is not working for me

Comment: not sure if `-` is affecting the parsing

Comment: @moth - Is possible share sample data by gdocs, dropbox... ?

Comment: work laptop , hard to access these domains. but essentially i wrote quickly the data in excel and saved into xlsb, only 3 rows. last row is `-`

Comment: thanks that works, but why the `D` unit ? is it because excel parses as days after a certain date ? is this date 1899-12-30 ? could you please give me some background on why this specific date. thanks

Comment: @moth - Because excel datetimes use days, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas)

Comment: thanks, I see that `date_parser` is being deprecated to `date_format` in pandas `2.0`

Comment: @moth - I think then need post processing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454403/convert-excel-style-date-with-pandas) with `df = pd.read_excel(p)`

Comment: treid using that : `df['ird'] = df.apply(lambda x : pd.to_timedelta(x, unit='D', errors='coerce') + pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30'))` but getting this : `pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsTimedelta: Cannot convert 1107496 days to timedelta64[ns] without overflow`

Comment: @moth - Use `df['ird'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ird'], unit='D', errors='coerce') + pd.Timestamp('1899-12-30')`