# I am getting value error while parsing it to date time format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

> ValueError: time data "44033" doesn't match format "%d/%m/%Y", at position 0.

You might want to try:
- passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
- passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
- passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

In my dataframe I have date column which pandas is recognizing it as a float. The following is what I used to convert it,

```py
df_1['Document Date'] = pd.to_datetime(
  df_1['Document Date'],
  format ='%d/%m/%Y', 
  origin='unix'
)
df_1
```

I have tried using chat GPT to help me

Comment: `44033` looks like Excel's serialized format of `21/07/20`. Easiest fix is to go back to your Excel-file and format the number as a date.

Comment: see [Convert Excel style date with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38454403/10197418)