# Python converting date from 5 digit code wrong

Tags: python, datetime

I imported excel data, and the date got changed automatically to 5 digits like '44309'.
I am using this code to try to change it on this test date since I know its supposed to equal '4/23/2021'.

```
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)+timedelta(44309)).strftime(%Y-%m-%d))
```

Its giving me '2091-04-25'.

Not sure what im doing wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359150/convert-date-from-excel-in-number-format-to-date-format-python

Comment: This happens because you are counting forward 44309 days from [the Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but Excel reckons dates from the beginning of the 20th century. In the future, please try to [figure out the requirements yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), for example by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+convert+excel+date).