# Converting Epoch date to human readable date

Tags: python, datetime

I’ve been trying to convert a column containing epoch dates to human readable format but I keep bumping into problems.

So I have a dataframe with a date column containing epoch dates ranging from 45329 all the way to 45413.

Now I extracted a singular value to test if the code works but it doesn’t, code below:

1.

```py
epoch_time = 45329
epoch_time_seconds = epoch_time
H_readable_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_time_seconds).strftime(‘%m-%d-%Y)
```

Output:
`01-01-1970`

Actual date:
`02-07-2024`   #(2nd Feb 2024)

2.

```py
epoch_time = 45329
epoch_time_seconds = epoch_time *24 * 3600 #assuming epoch time is in seconds 
H_readable_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_time_seconds).strftime(‘%m-%d-%Y)
```

Output:
`02-10-2094`

Actual date:
`02-07-2024`   #(2nd Feb 2024)

Not sure what’s wrong. Any help/inputs/corrections will be appreciated.

I have included the code. I am trying to convert the dates example from 45329 which in Excel when converted translates to 02-07-2024. I am trying to achieve this in python.

Comment: it seems you're mixing up ordinal dates that excel uses with Unix timestamps that the `fromtimestamp` method expects. are you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/29387137/10197418? or https://stackoverflow.com/q/31359150/10197418? for pandas see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460255/10197418

Comment: i agree -- those numbers don't look like epoch time. 45329 would be january 1, 1970 at 12:35 pm UTC.

Comment: @jkr to be precise, any incremental representation of time has an "epoch", i.e. an instant in time that serves as reference. The problem is that the naming isn't always that clear and if e.g. you're just starting out to work with time series data, you might not be aware that there are multiple common variants, both in terms of their epoch and their unit (seconds, days etc.).

Comment: @FObersteiner - thanks, i had no idea. whenever i hear epoch time, i assume seconds since jan 1, 1970.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime;datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900,1,1).toordinal()+45329-2)` results in the expected `datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 7, 0, 0)`