# Convert datetime.datetime object to days since epoch in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-formatting, epoch

I've got a `pandas.Series` object that might look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
myVar = pd.Series(["VLADIVOSTOK 690090", "MAHE", NaN, NaN, "VLADIVOSTOK 690090", "2000-07-01 00:00:00"])
```

`myVar[5]` is parsed as a `datetime.datetime` object when the data is read into Python via `pandas`. I'm assuming that converting this value to the number of days since epoch (36708) isn't difficult at all. I'm just new to Python and don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myVar = pd.Series(["VLADIVOSTOK 690090", "MAHE", "NaN", "NaN", "VLADIVOSTOK 690090", "2000-07-01 00:00:00"])

myVar[5] = pd.to_datetime(myVar[5]) - pd.datetime(1970,1,1)

print(myVar)
0     VLADIVOSTOK 690090
1                   MAHE
2                    NaN
3                    NaN
4     VLADIVOSTOK 690090
5    11139 days 00:00:00
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 43):

I'm not sure where you're getting 36,708 days since the epoch (it's only been 16,644 days since January 1, 1970), but `datetime.timedelta` objects (used in date arithmetic) have a `days` attribute:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days
16644
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have misspoke. You're right that epoch for Unix systems is January 1st, 1970. I'm working with Excel sheets, so the "epoch" is technically January 1st, 1900, but in practice is December 30th, 1899 in order to correct for it not being a leap year. Nevertheless, your solution works.

Comment: Ah, I see. In any case, you can see that the epoch date is easily changed. You can use whatever reference date you want in place of `1970, 1, 1`.

Comment: @brittenb: related: [How to convert a given ordinal number (from Excel) to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29387137/4279)

Comment: I like this answer. A little nicer to read: `from datetime import datetime; (datetime.today() - datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).days`.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert this to seconds since epoch first, then divide it out by the amount of seconds in a day (86,400 seconds in a day). Please note the integer division here - will not return a float.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
seconds = now.strftime("%s") # seconds since epoch
days = int(seconds) / 86400 # days since epoch
```

I added the import and now as an example of a datetime object I can play with.

Comment: Alternatively using `from time import time`: `time() // (24 * 60 * 60)`. That’s `17526.0` today. I used Python 3.6, but in Python 2.7 you can achieve the same by importing `from __future__ import division` (or better import all future imports).

Comment: I think you need to be careful with this, leap years and leap seconds can get in the way

Answer (score 1):

For a Pandas Dataframe:

```
df_train["DaysSinceEpoch"] = [i.days for i in df_train["date"] - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)]
```

Assuming that you want days since Unix Epoch of `1970-01-01` and you have a column of Pythonic `datetime64[ns]`.

And see my [other answer with the exact reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986041/converting-days-since-epoch-to-date/66427042#66427042).