# Converting days since epoch to date

Tags: python, date, datetime, epoch

How can one convert a serial date number, representing the number of days since epoch (1970), to the corresponding date string? I have seen multiple posts showing how to go from string to date number, but I haven't been able to find any posts on how to do the reverse.

For example, `15951` corresponds to `"2013-09-02"`.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> (datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 2) - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).days + 1
15951
```

(The `+ 1` because whatever generated these date numbers followed the convention that Jan 1, 1970 = 1.)

TL;DR: Looking for something to do the following:

```
>>> serial_date_to_string(15951)  # arg is number of days since 1970
"2013-09-02"
```

This is different from [Python: Converting Epoch time into the datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/python-converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime) because I am starting with days since 1970. I not sure if you can just multiply by 86,400 due to leap seconds, etc.

Comment: I'm also open to bash shell script solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Converting Epoch time into the datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400256/python-converting-epoch-time-into-the-datetime)

Comment: Use: `datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)  + datetime.timedelta(15951)`

Comment: thanks @SSNR - this works:
`datetime.datetime(1970,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(15951 - 1)`

Comment: you can also use `epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)` to get the epoch datetime, instead of hardcoding. then follow @SSNR

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `datetime` package as follows:

```
import datetime
def serial_date_to_string(srl_no):
    new_date = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1,0,0) + datetime.timedelta(srl_no - 1)
    return new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This is a function which returns the string as required.

So:

```
serial_date_to_string(15951)
```

Returns

```
>> "2013-09-02"
```

Comment: Be careful with the -1. This answer, like the question, assumes that day 1 will be 1970-01-01 and day 0 will be 1969-12-31.

If you want 1970-01-01 to be day 0, remove the -1 from the function.

Comment: Good comment @Zonyl. Using Javas `LocalDate` (`LocalDate.ofEpochDay(15951)`) will also return `2013-09-03`, this is what you probably want.

Comment: I spent 4 hours in datetime purgatory because pandas datetimeindex and matplotlib do not play nice when showing xticks.  This answer was a good work around.

Answer (score 5):

And for a Pandas Dataframe:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], unit="d")
```

... assuming that the "date" column contains values like `18687` which is days from Unix Epoch of `1970-01-01` to `2021-03-01`.

Also handles seconds and milliseconds since Unix Epoch, use `unit="s"` and `unit="ms"` respectively.

Also see my [other answer with the exact reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687420/convert-datetime-datetime-object-to-days-since-epoch-in-python/66430616#66430616).

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [package](https://pypi.org/project/eday) for conversions between epoch days and datetimes.

`pip install eday`, that has [to_date](https://github.com/mindey/eday/blob/4bd100d8429eb206f9a7cb77dc9f0df55982586d/eday/__init__.py#L56-L77) function:

```py
import eday

def serial_date_to_string(edays):
    date = eday.to_date(edays-1)
    return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```