# changing column data type using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with date column. Column includes "custom" and "general" datatypes. I want to change it all datetime format. "43891" means "01.03.2020 00:00:00"

```
TARİH
28.02.2020  00:00:00 -->custom
28.02.2020  00:00:00 -->custom
28.02.2020  00:00:00 -->custom
43891 -->general
43891 -->general
43891 -->general
.
.
```

Here what I have tried below, same problem with me (ref. [changing all dates to standard date time in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180685/changing-all-dates-to-standard-date-time-in-dataframe))

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def from_excel_ordinal(ordinal, _epoch0=datetime(1899, 12, 31)):
    if ordinal >= 60:
        ordinal -= 1  # Excel leap year bug, 1900 is not a leap year!
    return (_epoch0 + timedelta(days=ordinal)).replace(microsecond=0)

df = pd.read_excel('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/deneme1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
m = df['TARİH'].astype(str).str.isdigit()

df.loc[m, 'TARİH'] = \
df.loc[m, 'TARİH']\
  .astype(int)\
  .apply(from_excel_ordinal)

df['TARİH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TARİH'], errors='coerce')

df.to_excel('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/deneme1.xlsx',index=False)
```

When I apply these codes, I am sharing output below. "General type" cells turns to "NaT".

```
print(df.loc[3280:3286, 'TARİH'])

Output: 
2020-02-28
2020-02-28
2020-02-28
2020-02-28
NaT
NaT
NaT
Name: TARİH, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In this solution, [changing all dates to standard date time in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180685/changing-all-dates-to-standard-date-time-in-dataframe) all column is "general" datatype. Due to that problem is solved. But when I apply above codes to my dataframe, Column D format is turning to "datetime" format. Due to that I am taking below error when I run the codes 2nd time:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]
```

I will use these codes everyday. Due to that I need solve the format cell problem. I can try also other methods if you offer.

Also I have 3000 rows. So I'm not able to apply manual methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no answers came to question with pandas method. Due to that I used "pynput.mouse" library.

When you change the column style to "short date" with mouse controller method, **df['TARİH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TARİH'])** this code runs due to there are no mixed datetimes and integers passed array, whole column have same format.

If you have pandas or any other method, please answer.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import pandas as pd

#Go to desktop
mouse= Controller ()
mouse.move(1358,751)
mouse.click(Button.left, 1)

#Open folder
mouse.position=(632, 108)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,2)

#Open excel file
mouse.position=(354, 127)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,2)

#Select D column in excel
mouse.position=(250, 256)
time.sleep(10)
mouse.click(Button.left,1)

#Go to format cell area
mouse.position=(709, 87)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,1)

#Change format to short date
mouse.position=(663, 297)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,1)

#Close excel file
mouse.position=(1337, 11)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,1)

#Save excel file
mouse.position=(597, 400)
time.sleep(2)
mouse.click(Button.left,1)

#wait till excel close
time.sleep(3)

print("Formula writing operation is starting..")
df = pd.read_excel('D:\Documents\Desktop\deneme/2020 Data_çalışma.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df['TARİH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TARİH'])
print("Formula is written..")


Output:
TARİH
28.02.2020  00:00:00
28.02.2020  00:00:00
28.02.2020  00:00:00
01.03.2020  00:00:00
01.03.2020  00:00:00
01.03.2020  00:00:00
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `43891` is the number of days since a zero-date:

```
# zero_date = 1899-12-29
zero_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-01') - pd.to_timedelta(43891, unit='D')
```

And then you can do `np.select`:

```
# you need dayfist
custom = pd.to_datetime(df['TARİH'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')

# general type
df['TARİH'] = np.where(custom.isna(), df['TARİH'],
                       (custom - zero_date)/pd.to_timedelta('1D')
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but when I re-execute the code this error raised:
TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]. This code will run everyday, so everyday zero_date will be change. To contribute this code I need to check numerical datetime everytime. This is manual work

Comment: You can only execute it once. After that, `df['TARIH']` is already of `datetime` type, and cannot be converted to `timedelta`.

Comment: Yes, I understand it but I need repeatable codes. Maybe if I locate the "integer value" in column, codes may be repeatable. But I don't know how to do.

Comment: What do you mean repeatable? Don't you want to change the datatype? Repeatability should start from when you read the data. Anyway, try the new code, it should run *repeatedly*.

Comment: Repeatable means, I will use these codes for production follow. And I want to automate my work. If I open the excel everytime to check values, it won't be automation.

Comment: I tried new codes, again error : TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]  error line: general = zero_date + pd.to_timedelta(df['TARİH'], unit='D', errors='coerce') also np is not defined.

Comment: Updated, you don't need `general` for the final output.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. I' m new at python, sorry for too many questions :) I added "import numpy as np" but I' m taking this error: "TypeError: invalid type promotion" according to this line "(custom - zero_date)/pd.to_timedelta('1D')"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211438/discussion-between-caner-ucal-and-quang-hoang).