# ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to convert the timestamp column to datetime format in a pandas dataframe. I used:

```
df['My_Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['My_Datetime'])
```

df looks like:

```
    ID            Timestamp
0   AM12C         2002-11-30 00:00:00
2   BX900         2008-06-30 00:00:00
3   C1200         2012-06-30 00:00:00
                  ...
```

and it caught error:

```
ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array
```

I removed the duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False, inplace=True)
```

and tried again, but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing all dates to standard date time in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180685/changing-all-dates-to-standard-date-time-in-dataframe)

Comment: Looks like you have integers in your column, is this expected?

Comment: Hi @mozway Thanks, this was not expected but after checking the data it's indeed the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect adding `errors='coerce'` will help:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime

data = StringIO("""ID;Timestamp
AM12C;2002-11-30 00:00:00
BX900;2008-06-30 00:00:00
C1200;2012-06-30 00:00:00
Z9999;1000
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";")
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')
print(df.info())
```

Result:

```
      ID  Timestamp
0  AM12C 2002-11-30
1  BX900 2008-06-30
2  C1200 2012-06-30
3  Z9999        NaT
```

Comment: It will hide the error, but I believe this should not happen in the first place, OP should better ensure why there is a mixed type.

Comment: Can you add the output from `print(df.to_csv(index=False))` to your question to make the issue more reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

To get this error, you would need to already have converted to datetime, then replaced one value with an integer:

```
s = pd.Series(['2002-11-30 00:00:00', '2008-06-30 00:00:00', 0])
s = pd.to_datetime(s)
# works fine until here

s.iloc[-1] = 0
pd.to_datetime(s)
# now raises an error
```

output `ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array`

So, don't convert to datetime multiple times, and make sure to understand where this integer is coming from after the first conversion to datetime.