# python - convert 5 digit serial number to date format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter

i want to convert a column in a table from a csv.file that has dates in the format of Excel 5-digits. i used the code below

`Cab_Data['Date of Travel'].apply(lambda X: (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(int(x)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))`

i keep getting an error message saying 'incomplete input'. what I do please.

I have tried this code

I expect to the values in the column to be converted to dates. for example:

```
40055 = 12/3/22 (just an example).
```

Comment: your code is correct, but, at the lambda, you're declaring the X on uppercase and using it in lower case at int(x)

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I tried the code again and got the error message 'TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: 1) The error is saying `x` is already a timestamp. To confirm what does: `print(type(x))` return? 2) `(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(40055)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')  '01-09-2079'`

Answer (score 0):

**Errors in Posted Code**

- Corections to your code (missing parenthesis and use of X rather than x):

  `df['Date of Travel'].apply(lambda x:(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(days=int(x))).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))`
- But this gives incorrect dates since:

  - Excel 5 digit timestamp starts in 1900
  - while utcfromtimestamp(0)starts in 1970

**Working code**

We modify the function from [How to convert a given ordinal number (from Excel) to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387137/how-to-convert-a-given-ordinal-number-from-excel-to-a-date/29387450#29387450) by Martijn Pieters to convert from 5  digit Excel to the desired date format.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def from_excel_ordinal(ordinal: float, _epoch0=datetime(1899, 12, 31)) -> datetime:
    if ordinal >= 60:
        ordinal -= 1  # Excel leap year bug, 1900 is not a leap year!
    return (_epoch0 + timedelta(days=ordinal)).replace(microsecond=0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

*Usage*

```
df['Date of Travel'].apply(from_excel_ordinal)
```

**Test**

```
data = {'Date of Travel':[40055, 0, 4200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result = df['Date of Travel'].apply(from_excel_ordinal)
print(result)
```

*Output*

```
0    30-08-2009   # note: 40055 is Aug. 30, 2009 not March 12, 2022 as states in OP
1    31-12-1899
2    01-07-1911
Name: Date of Travel, dtype: object
```